# Kubernetes implicitly uses Nvidia files in container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, kubernetes, nvidia

I have a docker image and I want to deploy it in Kubernetes. The image is based on `nvidia/cuda:10.0-base`. One command of entrypoint is `rm -r /usr` (yes, this command raises questions, but it is needed).

Container works great when I run it on docker. I am sure that entrypoint is correctly and completely executed. But when I try to deploy this image on my k8s, container crushes with following error:

```sh
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/nvidia-smi': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-server': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/nvidia-debugdump': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.430.26': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-compiler.so.430.26': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.410.104': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.430.26': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.430.26': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.430.26': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.410.104': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.410.104': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-cfg.so.430.26': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.430.26': Device or resource busy
```

I successfully deployed this container with different entrypoint and got to shell of this container with `kubectl exec -it`. When I try to remove, for example, `/usr/bin/nvidia-smi` same `Device or resource busy` error is raised.

Neither `top` nor `lsof` show processes that use `/usr/bin/nvidia-smi` or any of the other files listed above.

`top` output:

```
      1 root      20   0    4636    848    768 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     19 root      20   0   72304   5860   5096 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     25 root      20   0   21540   4056   3456 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    447 root      20   0   39512   3740   3196 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top
```

How k8s can influence work of container?

Comment: Is there any chance it is mounting /usr over from the host so it can install host-level drivers of some kind?

Comment: @coderanger Thank you, you are right. I compared /usr dirs in containers on my host machine and k8s and find out that files I have problem with were added by k8s. My bad, should check if first.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer for better visibility so community can benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Files listed in question as busy were added to container by Kubernetes.